# VS 2010 Server Explorer Database Showing No Tables

Tags: visual-studio, oracle, entity-framework, server-explorer

I'm working on a .Net application that needs to read from an Oracle 10g database behind Siebel.  In VS 2010 Server Explorer, I've created a connection using the OracleClient type connector with a reference to the Oracle TNS service name as the "server name."  The "Test Connection" button shows that the connection is successful.  However, in the Server Explorer, when I go to expand the Tables, no tables are shown.  I know for a fact that there are 3000+ tables in the database (thanks Siebel).  Anyone know what's happening here?  I'd like to create an Entity Framework 4.0 Entity Data Model...

Thanks for the help!

Andy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had the hardest time trying to solve this issue myself.  There's very little useful documentation on the subject. Once you create a data connection and tested the connection click "Ok" then open up the server explorer window. Right click on the new oracle data connection and select "Change View".  By default "My Objects" are selected, try selecting "User Objects" or "All Objects".  Once you do, you should be able to see all of the objects under the data connection sub categories.

[image: oracle connection]

Comment: I have the same problem here. Though the options I get for "Change View" are "Default", "Object Type" and "Schema". Any Idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason could possibly be the Oracle version instance you're connecting against.  I was connecting to a 10g when I answered this post.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on connections, go to Filters, the "displayed schemas" property by default, it's your logon name to the connection. Change the schemas to dbo schema and update the property. Then you should see all the tables. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have privileges on the schema and/or tables?

Don't know VS2010 but it sounds to me like there's a setting to show you only your schema by default.

UPDATE: Oracle just announced a new [ODAC version, 11.2.0.1.1 Beta](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index112011beta.html?msgid=8718709&eid=4868927875&lid=1) with support for VS 2010. You might give that a shot.

Comment: Yes.  The username/password I'm using should be able to see all database objects.

Comment: In an Oracle db, each user has their own schema (ie set of tables) but can have privileges to select from tables in other schemas. It is very unlikely you have been given the username/password of the user with all the Siebel tables. You might need to expand a 'users', 'schemas' or 'databases' and look for tables under there.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Somehow, my permission to access a view got revoked. When this happened, the view disappeared from Server Explorer, and when I tried to access it I got a totally misleading "File/View does not exist" error message, instead of some sort of "Access denied" message.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation occurred for me, however this was with SQL Server 2008. Somehow the sql user account I was connecting with lost both read and write privileges. Once the account was given back those privileges I was able to access everything as expected.